# Elements lose position when resizing the browser

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am new to web design and i don't know how to resolve the following problem.

The elements are in fine position when the browser is maximized. But when the browser re-sizes the elements and especially the img elements move to different directions.

Any tip or advice would be really useful. I want either the img to stand in their position or to shrink according to the resizing.

Here is the [website](http://branduniverse.dk/Entrepreneur/)

And the code

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family:GillSansStd-Light;
}
#wrapper {
    width:auto;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
#header{ position:fixed;width:100%; height: 15%; background:rgb(218, 208, 185);}
#blank { width:100%; height: 15%; background:white;}
#messen { width:100%; height:85%; background:rgb(218, 208, 185); }
#arrangorerne { width:80%; height:80%; background:rgb(218, 208, 185); padding-top:15%;padding-left:20%; }
#forbesogende { width:80%; height:80%; background:rgb(218, 208, 185); padding-top:15%;padding-left:20%; }
#forudstillere { width:80%; height:100%; background:rgb(218, 208, 185); padding-top:15%;padding-left:20%; }
#tidnsted { width:80%; height:100%; background:rgb(218, 208, 185); padding-top:15%;padding-left:20%; }

#arrow{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 200px 200px 0;
    border-color: transparent rgb(90, 47, 37) transparent transparent;
}

#menutd{
    background-color:rgb(90, 47, 37);
}

#logotd{
    position:relative;
    background-color:rgb(90, 47, 37);
}
#logo{
    position:absolute;
    top:-10%;
    right:10%;
    width:75%;
}
#side_logotd{
    position:relative;
}
#side_logo{
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    left:-170%;
    top:0%;
}

#texttd p{
  vertical-align: middle; 
}
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
table.header_table{
    width:100%;
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0px;
}
table.text_table{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;    
}
table.pricetable{
    width: 20%;
    margin:10px;
    display:none;
    border:1px solid black;
}
table.pricetable td{
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding:5px;
}
h1{
    font-family:GillSansStd;
    padding-left:10px;
}
h2{
    font-family:GillSansStd;
    padding-left:10px;
}
p{
    font-family:GillSansStd-Light;
    margin-top:20px;
    line-height:1.5em;
    padding-left:10px;
}
a:link {
color: rgb(90, 47, 37);
}
/* visited link */
a:visited {
color: rgb(90, 47, 37);
}
/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
color: rgb(112, 94, 91);
}
/* selected link */
a:active {
color: rgb(112, 94, 91);
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <table class="header_table" border="0">
        <tr>
        <td width="10%"></td>
        <td width="10%"><div id="arrow"></div></td>
        <td width="50%" valign="bottom" id="menutd">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="#messen">Messen</a></li>
                <li><a href="#arrangorerne">Arrangørerne</a></li>
                <li><a href="#forbesogende">For besøgende</a></li>
                <li><a href="#forudstillere">For udstillere/partnere</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tid&sted</a></li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td width="30%" id="logotd"><img src="img/logo-negativ.png" id="logo"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="blank"></div>

<div id="messen">

<table class="text_table" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="20%" id="side_logotd"><img src="img/logo-element.png" id="side_logo"></td>
        <td width="50%" id="texttd">
            <h1>Velkommen til ENTREPRENEUR movement 2015</h1>
            <p>ENTREPRENEUR movement 2015 er en kombineret messe og kongress, der for alvor ønsker at sætte iværksætteriet på dagsordenen i Danmark. Det er et professionelt forum, hvor iværksættere og mindre virksomheder bl.a. kan udveksle erfaringer, søge rådgivning og finde finansiering.</p>

            <p>Med lanceringen af Entrepreneur movement 2015 ønsker vi et opgør med de forhold, der ligger til grund for, at dansk iværksætterkultur mistrives. Vi ønsker at sætte fokus på udfordringerne for danske iværksættere samt rejse en debat om, hvordan vi kan styrke iværksætteriet i Danmark. På Entrepreneur movement 2015 samler vi derfor de kræfter, der for alvor kan finde løsninger på iværksætterkulturens udfordringer i Danmark. Vi har som mål at forbedre iværksætterkulturen i Danmark, og vi vil gøre op med lønmodtagermentaliteten.</p>


            <p>Vi har opstillet følgende konkrete mål for festivalen:<br><br>
                <ul style="list-style-position:inside;  padding-left:30px;">
                <li>Vi vil øge antallet af iværksættere i Danmark</li>
                <li>Vi vil få flere danske iværksættere til at lykkedes med deres drøm</li>
                <li>Vi vil inspirere flere danske iværksættere til at videreudvikle deres forretning til vækstvirksomheder</li>
            </ul>
            </p>

        </td>
        <td width="30%"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="arrangorerne">
    <h1 style="margin-bottom:60px;">Arrangørerne</h1>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="15%"><img src="img/uffe.jpg"></td>
            <td width="30%" valign="top" style="padding-left:1em;padding-right:2em;"><b>Uffe Just</b><br>CEO & FOUNDER - BRAND UNIVERSE<br><br><b>BRAND UNIVERSE</b> arbejder til daglig med at rådgive og hjælpe iværksættere og mindre virksomheder med at lykkes med deres idéer og forretninger. BRAND UNIVERSE har et indgående kendskab til forholdene for iværksættere og mindre virksomheder, samt hvilke udfordringer disse virksomheder kæmper med.
</td>
            <td width="15%"><img src="img/jesper.jpg"></td>
            <td width="30%" valign="top" style="padding-left:1em;padding-right:1em;"><b>JESPER ÅNDAHL</b><br>CEO - Copenhagen Exhibition Group<br><br><b>Copenhagen Exhibition Group</b> har mere end 20 års erfaring med at arrangere danske og internationale messer og kongresser.</td>
            <td width="10%"> </td>
        </tr>
        </table>

</div>

<div id="forbesogende">
    <h1 style="margin-bottom:60px;">For besøgende</h1>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="80%"></td>
            <td width="20%"> </td>
        </tr>
        </table>

</div>


<div id="forudstillere">

    <h1 style="margin-bottom:60px;">For udstillere/partnere</h1>
    <p>Skab vækst i din og andres virksomheder. Entrepreneur movement 2015 afholdes for første gang i 2015, og det overordnede mål er at forbedre iværksætterkulturen i Danmark og gøre op med lønmodtagermentaliteten.</p>
    <p>Vi ønsker, at udstillerne er:<br><br>
        <ul style="list-style-position:inside;  padding-left:30px;">
        <li>Virksomheder, der arbejder med iværksættere og mindre virksomheder eller ønsker kontakt til denne målgruppe</li>
        <li>Kapitalinstitutioner på udkig efter nye investeringsprojekter</li>
        <li>Interesse- og brancheorganisationer, der opnår mulighed for at fremme deres synspunkter, sikre synlighed samt vise deres støtte til iværksætteri</li>
    </ul>
    </p>

    <h2><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DisplayText('facts')">Facts om stande</a></h2>
    <p id="facts" style="display:none;">Følgende er inkluderet i standpriserne:<br>
       2 m høje hvide stofvægge til nabo (tilkøb af yderligere væg: 180 kr. pr. løbende meter (bestilles hos OnFront)). <br>
       Strøm (1,8 KW) – et stik med 3 stikdåser<br>
       En lampe pr. ca. 5 m2 – 700 W gaslamper (projekttørlys<br>
    </p>
    <br>

    <h2><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DisplayText('standprice')">Standpriser</a></h2>
    <table id="standprice" class="pricetable">
        <tr>
            <td>Op</td><td>til</td> <td>&nbsp;44 m2: </td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>830,- kr. pr. m2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>45</td><td>–</td><td>&nbsp;80 m2: </td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>780,- kr. pr. m2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>81</td><td>–</td><td>126 m2: </td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>745,- kr. pr. m2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Over</td><td></td><td> 126 m2: </td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>705,- kr. pr. m2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <h2><a href="">Generelle lejebetingelser</a></h2>
    <br>
    <p><b>Bliv partner</b> kontakt Uffe Just på 70 70 76 70 og book et møde, så vi kan drøfte jeres mulighed for partnerskab.<br>
    For information om ledige stande kontakt Jesper Åndahl på 21 27 08 14.
</p>
</div>


<div id="tidnsted">
    <h1 style="margin-bottom:60px;">Tid&sted</h1>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: **You shouldn't work with absolute positioned elements** if you don't know how they work. It's a common mistake by beginners. When you resize the window, the elements you say they are moving, they stay where you want to stay them...

Comment: Ok but how can i place the image in the left without setting an absolute position with the attribute  left:-170%; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because almost all of your elements rely on the size of the window (via percentages) to compute where they are. Due to this, changing the size of the window changes the positions of all of your elements.

To fix this, try not to use percentage widths and heights as much. Personally I make a container div a fixed size (around 1000px) then if I need to use percentages they would be based on a fixed size, meaning the elements won't all move around.

EDIT: As mark suggested, use min-width:

```
<div id="container" style="min-width:900px;width:100%">
</div>
```

Which will make the div grow if the window is above 900px, but would stop the div shrinking below it. Or a fixed size, so the container doesn't shrink or grow:

```
<div id="container" style="width:1000px">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: See the other answer.

Comment: Certainly, either use min-width like Mark suggested or use a fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a minimum width on a container elements.
Wrap content in something like this:

```
<div id="contentContainer">
      // Content goes here....
</div>
<style>
    #contentContainer {
       min-width:970px;
      margin:0 auto; <-- This will center the content, not necessary
     }
</style>
```